# SetOnClickListener en RecyclerView con envío de información a otro Activity en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, kotlin, android-intent, onclicklistener

**Estoy realizando una aplicación en Android Studio con Kotlin, en la cuál se requiere agregar un OnClickListener en los elementos de un RecyclerView, quiero mandar información al hacer click en algún elemento de la lista e imprimirla en un nuevo activity, pero tengo un error en un Intent.**
[image: Este es mi código, y el error que me marca]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Alex, acostumbra agregar tu código como texto en lugar de imagen, te recomiendo revisar [ask] y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio. En este caso pon el puntero sobre el error y te mostrará un mensaje conteniendo el detalle del error, agrégalo a tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no das muchos detalles en tu pregunta, lo mas probable es que tu clase `Place` no implemente la interfaz `Serializable` para utilizar la sobrecarga de [`putIntent(string, Serializable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)).

Intenta implementando esta interfaz:

```
class Place : Serializable
{
  //...

}
```